# Laravel $validator->validated() method is not throwing exception when the field under validation that fails is an array of values

Tags: laravel

Laravel `$validator->validated()` method is supposed to throw an exception if a rule fails, but when i use an array of values that is under validation incorporating a custom validation rule no exception is thrown.

So i have the following example in the routes/api.php file:

```
<?php

use App\Rules\Uppercase;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;

Route::get('/validation', function () {
    $data = [
        'name' => 'testname',
        'environments' => [
            'testenv1',
            'testenv2',
        ]
    ];
    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5', 'max:255'],
        'environments' => [
            'required',
            'nullable',
            'array',
            new Uppercase
        ]
    ]);
    try {
        $validator->validated();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        dd('caught by the exception thrown', $e->validator->failed());
    }

    dd('nothing happened');
})->name('validation');
```

Now when i run the above case instead of receiving a ValidationException as i would expect, since my provided environments data are all lowercase, the "nothing happened" string is shown.

The custom validation rule that i use is a modified version of Laravel's documentation uppercase rule to support an array of values instead of just a string -> https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#custom-validation-rules
The actual uppercase custom validation rule can be seen below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule;
use Illuminate\Translation\PotentiallyTranslatedString;

class Uppercase implements ValidationRule
{
    /**
     * Run the validation rule.
     *
     * @param Closure(string): PotentiallyTranslatedString $fail
     */
    public function validate(string $attribute, mixed $value, Closure $fail): void
    {
        foreach ($value as $index => $item) {
            if (strtoupper($item) !== $item) {
                $fail('The :attribute must be uppercase.');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Digging deeper i saw that the first thing `$validator->validated()` method checks to decide whether to throw an exception is the `$validator->invalid()` method, which in turn this method contains the following line:
`$failed = Arr::only(Arr::dot($invalid), array_keys($this->failed()));` and by using `Arr::dot($invalid)` instead of something like plain `$invalid` array it misses environments uppercase validation errors.

It seems to me like an erroneous behavior.

Can you please direct me if i am missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing something indeed, but it's not trivial. The `validated` phpdoc says it can throw a `ValidationException`, but regarding some conditions first.

If you look down at the implementation, you can see this:

```php
public function validated()
{
    throw_if($this->invalid(), $this->exception, $this);
    /* rest of the implementation */
}
```

I'll let you dig more deeply, but the point is, the validator state is not invalid at the moment you're calling `$validator->validated()` as it has not been validated. A way to check it is to write these simple pest tests:

```php
test('uppercase validation rule when validating the validator', function () {
    $data = [
        'name' => 'testname',
        'environments' => [
            'testenv1',
            'testenv2',
        ],
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5', 'max:255'],
        'environments' => [
            'required',
            'nullable',
            'array',
            new Uppercase,
        ],
    ]);

    $validator->validate();
    $validator->validated();

    $this->fail('should have thrown an exception');
})->throws(ValidationException::class);

test('uppercase validation rule when not validating the validator', function () {
    $data = [
        'name' => 'testname',
        'environments' => [
            'testenv1',
            'testenv2',
        ],
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($data, [
        'name' => ['required', 'string', 'min:5', 'max:255'],
        'environments' => [
            'required',
            'nullable',
            'array',
            new Uppercase,
        ],
    ]);

    $validator->validated();
})->throwsNoExceptions();
```

Thus you just have to remember to call the `$validator->validate()` method first

Comment: Cool and thank you for your answer.
So what is the purpose of calling 2 methods (->validate() and then ->validated()) instead of just calling just ->validated() since both contain similar check to throw an exception?

The only difference is the $this->invalid() check in the throw_if in validated() where validate() incorporates the $this->fails() in it's throw_if check.

My point here is why using throw_if($this->invalid(), $this->exception, $this); in validated() method instead of just using the same line just like in validate() which is throw_if($this->fails(), $this->exception, $this);?

Comment: You can actually use other validation method, like `fail` or `passes` I guess. Think is the class is not stateless, so I guess it makes sense. It's like having a class "Car". If you do `car.pressAccelerator()`, then even if you didn't do `start()` before, it shouldn't throw an exception. It just doesn't move the car.

On the other hand, doing `car.start()`, but without having an engine, you might expect an exception. If you disagree, feel free to ask more on the Laravel's discussion tab on github (or their Discord)

Also feel free to accept the answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Ok, but my objection is that the check of `$this->invalid()` in `validated()` method is erroneous and should change since the check to throw an exception just like in `validate()` exists or else is redundant. In my case i am resolving the FormRequest in a middleware thus i do not have access to validator object since it is protected so i had to extend this to get the resolved validator instance. In any case many thanks.